# EXtract image from intent type */* in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I used Intent Filter in manifest file, so that other app can share image to my app. It is working perfectly but if someone share a whole folder from the ES File manager then I got the Intent Type as `*/*` (obviously contains the whole uri of files).

As my application deals with only images and I want to skip all the remaining uri other than image type.

Is their any solution for this?

Edit:
[image]

Comment: Well what exactly is the problem? And what do you wanna change? The behaviour of your app or that of es file explorer?

Comment: `(obviously contains the whole uri of files).` ??? Unclear what you get.

Comment: When I share a folder from a file explorer and choose my app to get the image files but that folder contains videos also, how can I skip the video files and only take image files. As I get all the uri's in the Intent

Comment: How does one share a folder with ES FIle Explorer? I dont see such a possibility.

Comment: You can see this on WhatsApp also. pick a folder of images that contains other media too and share it to WhatsApp, we can see that WhatsApp can only pick images and show the preview of it.

Comment: That does not answer my remark. Please tell how to pick a folder with ES File Explorer and then share the folder. You said you could do that. I see no such option.

Comment: Question edited: please see the image

Comment: Indeed a new ES File Explorer can share a folder. But one gets the file paths of files in it. With file name and extension. So seeing the extension you can handle accordingly. What is the problem?

Comment: Although it can be extracted using loop or linq (with several image formats like jpg, jpeg, bmp, ico, png) but I was looking for something like filter that can easily filter all types of images. Isn't there any ?

Comment: I dont know what you want. You just get from ES File Explorer a list of all files in the choosen folder. Your app has to decide which files it will use. What is the problem?

Comment: As we get list of all files that might contains some other files like .nomedia or any other files. As android can filter the image like image/*, I am looking something like to filter images from all list of files.